# drawer functionality not drawing the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation-drawer

Hi i am using [EZSwipeController](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController) for the drawing functionality. I made it work according to need But the problem is that i have some buttons on the navigation bars, So while calling the viewcontroller using EZSwipeController it is not populating the navigation bar of the pulled views.